# How can I get the map object for a Leaflet map from the ID of the div element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, leaflet

A previous developer created a map using Leaflet on the page. The Javascript is very complex and I cannot find where the Leaflet map is instantiated. However, I know which DOM element is associated with the map. Is there any way to get the Leaflet map object from the id of the element?

I.e., the element id is #city-map. L.map('city-map') returns

```
Error: Map container is already initialized.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No: Leaflet does not set a reference back to the map object from the DOM element, because that can easily cause memory leaks. And `L.map` always creates a new map - it does not find a map like you might expect coming from jQuery. You'll need to decipher the code from your other developer and find the variable the map is assigned to.